# My 'show progress thread' doesn't run when it counts

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, model-view-controller, mfc

I have a thread that does lengthy processing. While I am waiting for the thread to finish, I kick start another 'show progress' thread which simply toggles a bitmap back and forth to show program is crunching on data. To my surprise this approached didn't work at all.

My 'show progerss' thread simply stop updating (=running) when the main activity starts and it starts updating when that activity ends. This is nearly the oppose of what I want! Should I expect this behavior because of the `WaitForSingleOBject`which is in wait state for most of the time and wakes up briefly?

```
 // This is the main thread that does the actual work
 CWinThread* thread = AfxBeginThread(threadDoWork, this, THREAD_PRIORITY_LOWEST, 0, CREATE_SUSPENDED );
         thread->m_bAutoDelete = FALSE;
         thread->ResumeThread();

// before I start to wait on the above thread, I start this thread which will toggle image to show application is processing
 AfxBeginThread(ProgressUpdateThread, &thread_struct_param, THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL, 0 );

 // wait for the main thread now.
 DWORD dwWaitResult = WaitForSingleObject( thread->m_hThread, INFINITE );

 DWORD exitCode;
 ::GetExitCodeThread( thread->m_hThread, &exitCode );
 delete thread;

 // This thread toggles image to show activity 
 UINT ProgressUpdateThread(LPVOID param) 
 {
     CEvent * exitEvent = ((mystruct *)param)->exitEvent;
     MyView *view ((mystruct *)param)->view;

     int picture = 0;

     do
     {
         waitResult =  WaitForSingleObject( exitEvent->m_hObject, 100);

         if (waitResult == WAIT_TIMEOUT)
         {

            picture = toggle ? 1: 0;

             // invert
             toggle =  !toggle;

             View->Notify( UPDATE_IMAGE, picture );
         }
         else if (waitResult == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
         {
             return TRUE;
         }
     }
     while( 1);
 }
```

Another consideration in my solution is that I would like to not touch the actual 'DoWork' thread code and that's also why I am using separate thread to update GUI. Can I make this approach work? Is the only way to update GUI reliable is to update it from the actual 'DoWork thread itself?

I do want to clarify that my 'Show progress' thread does the job perfectly if the application is idle, but if I launch the worker thread operation (in lower thread priority), the update gui thread simply stops running and resume only when the worker finishes.

I am using Windows 7.

Comment: In general anytime a progress thread fails to update a UI it is because said-UI is not pumping messages through a message loop. Its been *forever* since I did thread-work in MFC, but there must be samples on how to accomplish this properly *somewhere*. Perhaps [`MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684242(v=vs.85).aspx) (read the docs *carefully*, its a little tricky to use) and a properly managed msg-pump will do what you want. It sounds like your main thread is busy crunching something and isn't servicing its loop

Comment: Actually in this case, I am updating the GUI directly from update-gui thread. I know there are pros and cons of that but as long as one thread updates gui, it should be okay.

Comment: It should work then. If you're main-thread is indeed servicing a msg-loop something else must be missing.

Comment: The evidence directly implicates the worker thread. Whenever it starts running, gui-updates stops updating. When it stops running gui-updates starts updating. I demonstrated this by running the gui-thread independently at all times and it does stops updating when my other work thread starts. I will keep digging more.

Comment: As you have shown it, the main UI thread is completely blocked waiting on the processing thread, and you are using a third thread to update the UI. UI controls can't always be updated in other threads like that, and it is the wrong design to use anyway. Let the main UI thread continue servicing its own UI normally. You don't need the third thread at all. Don't block the main UI thread waiting for the processing thread. The main UI thread can show a non-modal window/dialog/whatever as needed and then run a secondary message loop to service the UI until the processing thread is finished....

Comment: The main UI thread can then use a standard timer, or even a `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` loop, to keep the bitmap updated.

Comment: I have to/(actually, *get to*) agree with Remy on this. If at all possible, it should be used for everything UI driven if possible. That's the way I always did it in the past (think the last MFC app I did this with was with VS2003 if that tells you anything).

Answer (score 2):

Your design is all wrong and over-complicated for what you are attempting.  Try something more like this simpler solution:

```
bool toggle = false;

VOID CALLBACK updateProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, UINT_PTR idEvent, DWORD dwTime)
{
    int picture = toggle ? 1: 0;
    toggle = !toggle;
    View->Notify( UPDATE_IMAGE, picture );
}
```

```
CWinThread* thread = AfxBeginThread(threadDoWork, this, THREAD_PRIORITY_LOWEST, 0, CREATE_SUSPENDED );
thread->m_bAutoDelete = FALSE;
thread->ResumeThread();

UINT_PTR updateTimer = SetTimer(NULL, 0, 100, updateProc);

do
{
    DWORD dwWaitResult = MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, &(thread->m_hThread), FALSE, INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT );
    if (dwWaitResult == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
        break;

    if (dwWaitResult == (WAIT_OBJECT_0+1))
    {
        MSG msg;
        while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        } 
    } 
}
while (true);

KillTimer(NULL, updateTimer);

DWORD exitCode;
::GetExitCodeThread( thread->m_hThread, &exitCode );
delete thread;
```

If you do not want to use a standalone procedure for the timer, you can adjust the parameters of `SetTimer()` to have it post `WM_TIMER` messages to an `HWND` of your choosing instead, and then do the UI updates in that window's message procedure as needed.  You would still need the message loop to pump the timer messages, though.

The alternative is to simply not do any waiting at all.  Once you start the worker thread, move on to other things, and let the worker thread notify the main UI thread when it is done with its work.

Comment: I agree with your comment to OP but I am afraid I am not entirely on board with your solution. I did made gui to update and I will post my own answer as proposed solution.

Answer (score 0):

Remy Lebeau pointed out correctly that my main GUI thread was actually waiting on the worker thread. Now since my worker gui-update thread was (obviously) calling gui function, it was in turn blocked on main GUI thread. I realized even SetWindowText() from a third thread will put that thread in wait if the main GUI thread is in wait or blocked state.

I don't like to use PeekandPump() mechanism, I thought it was a bad design smell. It was originally used in early windows (before win95 I think) which were not truly multitasking. To the best of my knowledge this should not be used now.

My solution was to put the whole code that I posted in OP in a new thread. So my button click in gui creates this threat and returns immediately. This master worker thread can now wait on other threads and my GUI will never block. When it gets completed, it post a message to the parent window to notify it. The bitmap is now changed perfectly using a separate gui-update thread when the application is processing in another thread.

Comment: You are correct that the best solution is to put lengthy operations into a worker thread and not block the main UI thread at all. But you should not be using worker threads to update the UI directly. That is the responsibility of the main UI thread, and the main UI thread only. Worker threads can post to the main UI thread to tell it what to update, but the main UI thread needs to be the one to actually perform them. And creating a separate thread just to update your bitmap is overkill and unnecessary. Use a simple timer instead, or even switch to an animated GIF/AVI control instead.

Comment: You are right, ideally the main GUI thread should be doing the updating. Also in a perfect world of multithreading applications, any notifications from the process worker thread should also be a PostMessage() as well and never SendMessage() but for practical purposes some comprises can be accepted. For example I have an observer pattern working for this which does't really work in true multithreaded environment. But thankfully SendMessage() like call into the view just do fine in separating the GUI from business logic.

Comment: My model does sends a message to the view which does the actual updating. So although updating is done in the view but it is owned by (or rather triggered) by worker thread, the main GUI thread does the actual updating. The only downsize is that that worker thread is waiting for main GUI thread to do the actual update only than it returns and this is what I mean a little comprise - this doesn't take much time and it is rather desirable to couple it with processing thread.